# GridSplitter с контейнером внутри

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, можно ли как-то в GridSplitter засунуть контейнер, чтобы туда можно было поместить какой-нибудь контент?

Очень хочется сужать/расширять окно, но чтобы еще в середине окна были какие-нибудь кнопочки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6568410/12888024 из любого контрола можно сделать что угодно, переназначив ему `Template`.

Comment: Если следовать этому примеру, то кнопки, которые я туда добавляю не работают и при нажатии на них, только ресайзить сам сплиттер можно=(

Comment: Задайте кнопке например `Panel.ZIndex="10"`